# PHP Switching Timezones / Retrieving MySQL Data

Tags: php, mysql, date, timezone

I display a system status table on my site that has a row for each of the last 14 days (including day).  Then for each column, I select any events that have occurred for that day from a MySQL database.

All data in MySQL is stored in UTC and PHP is operating under UTC as well.  I'm having two issues:

1. If the user is in Eastern time for example, the grid was updating to display tomorrow's date even though it was only 8pm for the Eastern user.  I think I've solved that by doing this:

   ```
   while ($i < 14)
       {       
           //SET STATUS DATE
           $status_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-$i day"));

           //LOCALIZE TIMES    
           $status_date = new DateTime($status_date);
           $status_date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));

           echo $status_date->format("F j, Y");
       }
   ```
2. The next issue I'm having is on the search for events.  Each event has an INCIDENT_START field in the database and I query like this:

   ```
   SELECT INCIDENT_STATUS FROM TABLE_system_status WHERE SYSTEM_AFFECTED='WEBSITE' AND INCIDENT_START BETWEEN '$start_time' AND '$end_time' ORDER BY INCIDENT_START DESC LIMIT 1
   ```

Here's my issue.  If I use `$start_time = $status_date->format("Y-m-d 00:00:00")` and `$end_time = $status_date->format("Y-m-d 23:59:59")`, incidents are not displayed on the correct day within the table.

Example:
An event in the database has an INCIDENT_START time of 2013-03-19 01:02:01 UTC which is equal to 2013-03-18 21:02:01 EDT.  However, in this case, it's still showing up on the March 19th column of my table.

Bottom line....I need to be able to get events from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 in the user's local time even though they're in UTC in the database.  I have a feeling I'm over complicating this but I've tried a bunch of different combinations and can't seem to get it right.  Really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `$status_date` in the user's local timezone and convert to UTC.

```
$status_date = new DateTime("today -$i day", new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
$status_date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

$start_time = $status_date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$status_date->add(new DateInterval('PT23H59M59S'));
$end_time = $status_date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  I tried your code and it seems to be still giving me the start/end in eastern time.  Output of `$status_date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s T")` yields 2013-03-21 19:09:15 EDT.  Then for start_time I get 2013-03-21 00:00:00 and end_time I get 2013-03-21 23:59:59.  Shouldn't I get 2013-03-21 04:00:00 and 2013-03-22 03:59:59 which are the UTC equivalents?

Comment: Thanks a million - that worked perfectly.  If you've got time, could you explain how the `DateInterval('PT23H59M59S')` does just for my own education?  I did a bit of searching but can't find anything helpful.  Thanks again!

Comment: DateInterval uses the ISO 8601 Durations format. Wikipedia has an explanation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations

Comment: P = "period", T = "Time" (to separate time and date parts), 23H = 23 hours, 59M = 59 minutes, 59S = 59 seconds

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can do it for you:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(INCIDENT_STATUS, 'UTC', 'EST') ...
```

relevant docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz